# Getting if a user is followed by logged in user, not working

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a user following system that works well until I try to get info if I am following the user, but it just does not work. Here is a sample of the code.

#### What is wrong

In the `serializers.py` of the user, I am trying to get a check if the logged-in user follows the current user he is checking. I tried to set it to give one of 3 responses: `True`, `False`, or `"not following"`. I am doing this in the user serializer so on the API can display some things based on the value.

#### Some things to note about how follow and unfollow works in this app

The status plays a huge role here, there are three statuses, for now, `followed`, `unfollowed`, and `blocked`. When the user follows, the status is set to `followed` upon creation, when unfollowed, the user is not deleted but instead the status changes to `unfollowed`, it was designed like this to save more data like time unfollowed and the rest.

#### What happens when I run the code below

When I run the code, it recognizes myself when I view my profile and returns the appropriate message, but when I am viewing a user I follow, I get the **response1**. in that response, since I get `"not following"` instead of a `True`/`False`, it means that the `try` block failed.

I also noticed that if in the serializer in the `get_am_i_following()` function I change `filter(slug=user.slug)` to `filter(pk=user.pk)` it runs but I get `False` (as shown in **response2** below) when in fact I am supposed to get `True`.

models.py

```py
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True, blank=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['fullname']

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def follow_a_user(self, user_to_follow):
        # find user by slug
        try:
            user_to_follow = User.objects.get(slug=user_to_follow)
        except:
            return False, 'User not found'

        if user_to_follow != self:
            try:
                log = FollowLog.objects.get(
                    user=user_to_follow,
                    followed_by=self,
                )
                log.set_as_followed()
                return True, 'Refollow successful'
            except:
                FollowLog.objects.create(
                    user=user_to_follow,
                    followed_by=self,
                    status=FollowStatus.following.value
                )
                return True, 'Follow Successful'
        else:
            return False, 'Cannot follow oneself'

    def unfollow_a_user(self, user_to_unfollow):
        # find user by slug
        try:
            user_to_unfollow = User.objects.get(slug=user_to_unfollow)
        except:
            return False, 'User not found'

        if user_to_unfollow != self:
            try:
                log = FollowLog.objects.get(
                    user=user_to_unfollow,
                    followed_by=self,
                )
                log.set_as_unfollowed()
                return True, 'UnFollow Successful'
            except Exception as e:
                return False, 'User doesnt follow the specified user' if 'exist' in e else e
        else:
            return False, 'Cannot unfollow oneself'


class FollowStatus(enum.Enum):
    following = 'following'
    unfollowed = 'unfollowed'
    blocked = 'blocked'


FOLLOW_STATUS = (
    ('following', 'following'),
    ('unfollowed', 'unfollowed'),
    ('blocked', 'blocked'),
)


class FollowLog(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='followers')
    followed_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                    related_name='following', null=True)
    followed_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.CharField(choices=FOLLOW_STATUS, default=FollowStatus.following.value, max_length=30)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    unfollowed_on = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    blocked_on = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} followed by {} ".format(self.user, self.followed_by)

    def set_as_followed(self):
        self.status = FollowStatus.following.value
        self.save()

    def set_as_blocked(self):
        self.status = FollowStatus.blocked.value
        self.blocked_on = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def set_as_unfollowed(self):
        self.status = FollowStatus.unfollowed.value
        self.unfollowed_on = timezone.now()
        self.save()
```

serializers.py

This is the place I am trying to make the magic happen, where I return the statements if the user(logged in) follows the other user we are checking his profile. We are doing this with the `get_am_i_following` function.

```py
class CustomUserDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    '''
    a custom serializer for
    the user to view his own data
    '''
    profiles = ProfileSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    showcase = ShowcaseSlugSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    followers_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    following_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    am_i_following = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('pk','email', 'fullname', 'profiles', 'slug', 'showcase', 'followers_count', 'following_count', 'am_i_following')
        read_only_fields = ('email', 'fullname', 'profiles', 'slug', 'showcase')

    def get_followers_count(self, instance):
        return instance.followers.all().filter(status='following').count()

    def get_following_count(self, instance):
        return instance.following.all().filter(status='following').count()

    def get_am_i_following(self, instance):
        '''
        returns =
            (
                Myself- when the user i am checking if i follow, is myself
                following- when i am following user
                not following- when user isnt following or when not logged in
            )
        '''
        try:
            request = self.context.get("request")
            user = request.user
            if user==instance:
                return 'Myself'
            else:
                return instance.followers.filter(status='following').filter(slug=user.slug).exists()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return "not following"
```

views.py

```py
class UserRetriveAPIView(APIView):
    '''
    Gets a particular user in the database using the slug as the lookup
    '''
    serializer_class = CustomUserDetailsSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, IsUserOrReadOnly]

    def get(self, request, slug):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, slug=slug)

        serializer_context = {"request": request}
        serializer = self.serializer_class(user, context=serializer_context)

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

urls.py

```py
path("users/<slug:slug>/", UserRetriveAPIView.as_view(), name="users-detail")
```

Normally running the code when `filter(slug=user.slug)` in the `get_am_i_following` function gives me the JSON response where it runs the except code

response1

```
{
    "pk": 1,
    "email": "odedeyiopeyemi94@gmail.com",
    "fullname": "Opeyemi David Odedeyi",
    "profiles": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "skills": [],
            "user": "opeyemi-david-odedeyi-7ug3j0",
            "date_of_birth": null,
            "bio": null,
            "profile_photo": null,
            "sex": null,
            "type_of_body": null,
            "feet": null,
            "inches": null,
            "lives_in": null,
            "updated_on": "2019-12-06T19:31:38.307863+01:00"
        }
    ],
    "slug": "opeyemi-david-odedeyi-7ug3j0",
    "followers_count": 1,
    "following_count": 2,
    "am_i_following": "not following"
}
```

But changing the code when `filter(slug=user.slug)` in the `get_am_i_following` function gives me the JSON response but this time returns false when it is supposed to return true

```
{
    "pk": 1,
    "email": "odedeyiopeyemi94@gmail.com",
    "fullname": "Opeyemi David Odedeyi",
    "profiles": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "skills": [],
            "user": "opeyemi-david-odedeyi-7ug3j0",
            "date_of_birth": null,
            "bio": null,
            "profile_photo": null,
            "sex": null,
            "type_of_body": null,
            "feet": null,
            "inches": null,
            "lives_in": null,
            "updated_on": "2019-12-06T19:31:38.307863+01:00"
        }
    ],
    "slug": "opeyemi-david-odedeyi-7ug3j0",
    "followers_count": 1,
    "following_count": 2,
    "am_i_following": false
}
```

[UPDATED]

And just to be sure, when I get the same users followers I get the logged in user which is the more reason it should return `True`

```
[
    {
        "followed_by": "olajumoke-dehinbu-3707yd"
    }
]
```

running `exceptions as e` gave me

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'slug' into field. Choices are: blocked_on, followed_by, followed_by_id, followed_on, id, status, unfollowed_on, updated_on, user, user_id
```

Comment: what is the error that causes the except block? you could print it before `return "not following"` statement

Comment: @hashlash I am not sure I understand, but I updated the code to what I think you were asking about

Comment: change the `except:` to `except Exception as e:` and add `print(e)` before `return "not following"` to see the error

Comment: @hashlash I just did that and updated the code. I am quite surprised that slug is not in the field

Comment: @hashlash please any progress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
instance.followers.filter(status='following').filter(slug=user.slug).exists()
```

There is your mistake. For example, with your models, if you call

```
instance.followers.filter(status='following')
```

You will get all `FollowLog` models where `user` field is the user we are checking his profile. And now you must check is user(logged in) follows him. But in `FollowLog` model the user who follows are in `followed_by` field.

So try:

```
instance.followers.filter(status='following').filter(fallowed_by=user).exists()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked and I have learned something big from you. I really appreciate.